# Using .so libraries with problematic name in Gradle file

Tags: java, android, c++, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build a **build.gradle** file and I have a problem with a specific library's name.

I want to add **'libc++.so'** to my apk but the **'++'** is interpreted as an operator, I tried escaping the **'++'** but with no results. My specific problem is in this code:

```
libc++ {
            headers.srcDir "../xxx/xxx/inc/"
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("../xxx/xxx/xxx/libs/libc++.so")
            }
        }
```

And I get the following syntax error:

```
Error:(53, 0) startup failed:
build file 'C:\work\xxx\app\build.gradle': 53: expecting '}', found '{' @ line 53, column 20.
               libc++ {
                      ^
1 error
```

How can I add the library to my apk?

Comment: I suspect you can just quote it: `"libc++" { ... }`.

Comment: Can u not rename the so file?? I guess renaming doesn't create any problem

Comment: Thanks Oliver Charlesworth it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided by Oliver Charlesworth in the comments.

You can just quote the string, like so:

```
"libc++" { ... }
```